# PhpStorm IdeaVim highlight and jump to search term before hitting enter (like Sublime Text or Vim)

Tags: phpstorm, ideavim

In Sublime Text with Vi mode or Vim, when you start searching for:

```
/foobar
```

all instances of "foobar" are not only highlighted but the editor "jumps" down to the first instance of the search term without having to hit enter.

But in PhpStorm with IdeaVim, when I type in

```
/foobar
```

nothing happens until I hit enter, in other words, I don't know if I have partial or full matches until I press the enter key.

I can get IdeaVim to highlight **after** pressing enter if I have

```
:set hls
```

IdeaVim will highlight all of the "foobar" matches in red.

Does anyone know how to configure PhpStorm or IdeaVim to automatically highlight **and** jump to the first instance of my search term **before** I hit enter?

Answer (score 1):

IdeaVim doesn't support this feature yet (0.39). There is a feature request for it at IdeaVim's issue tracker: [VIM-271](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-271), you can vote for it to receive status updates.