# How to set the search results color of ideavim in pycharm?

Tags: colors, pycharm, ideavim

Recently I switch from vim to Pycharm to program and have installed ideavim plugin. It works well in most cases. When I search for a text, it finds the result, but the searching result has no highlighting color, e.g. I typed 'first_pos' in the command line, and the result shows, but no highlighting color in the word (sorry I can not post image...).

How to change the search result color of ideavim? Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Try this in the console:

```
:set hls
```

Taken from this related question: [PhpStorm IdeaVim highlight and jump to search term before hitting enter (like Sublime Text or Vim)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985861/phpstorm-ideavim-highlight-and-jump-to-search-term-before-hitting-enter-like-su?rq=1)

Comment: PSA: To get it to work globally add it to your `.ideavimrc` file. Also consider `set incsearch` command to highlight while typing search.